# To camelCase or not to camel_case

Tags: java, coding-style

What is the standard when coding in Java, when do you use camel case when do you use underscores etc.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You stick with the [Java Code Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html).

What exactly the standard is doesn't matter - what matters is that everyone follows it, and you should too.

Comment: One could also refer to [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) (section 5. Naming)

Answer (score 21):

**ClassName**

- Renderer
- HttpSession

**methodName**

- applyTo()
- run()

**instanceVariable** / **localVariable**

- currentUser
- threadList

**CONSTANT_NAME**

- LOG
- DEFAULT_CONTEXT

**G** (Generic Type Parameter)

- T
- E

Comment: Don't forget generic parameters.

Comment: What is the standard for acronyms in camel case?

e.g. getURL() vs. getUrl()